# Eigenvalues for the second order differential operator

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Show for the linear mapping

$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}:C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}): f(x)\mapsto \frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}$

has an eigenvalue for every $t\in \mathbb{R}$ with $t$ being min dimension 2.

---

I found a proof for the first order differential operator. The proof deals with the function $f(x)=e^{tx}$

So My question is why can I chose this function and how to proof this for the second order differential operator? What about the dimension 2 of $t$?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what it means for a number $t$ to be 2 dimensional, but for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$ there is a function which satisfies:

$$ \frac{d^2}{dx^2} f = t f$$

If $t\geq 0 $ then

$$ f(x) = A e^{\sqrt{t} x} + B e^{-\sqrt{t} x} $$
and if $t<0$ then

$$ f(x) = A \cos (\sqrt{-t} x) + B \sin (\sqrt{-t} x) $$